Show that $(I+M)^{-1}M$ is positive semi-definite if $M$ is positive semi-definite.
Let $M$ be some semi-definite matrix and symmetric. I'm trying to show that $(I+M)^{-1} M$ is also positive semi-definite.
In general, it is clear to me that $(I+M)^{-1}$ is positive definite, but I'm not sure whether the product of a positive definite and semi-definite matrix is always semi-definite as well.

Hint: $x/(1+x)\ge 0$ if $x\ge 0$

@Exodd Your hint convinces me more that it is true, however, I don't see a way to translate it to the situation with a matrix $M$ "instead of" $x$.

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$. Then let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $M$. By the spectral mapping theorem,
$$ \{\frac{\lambda_i}{1+\lambda_i}: \lambda_i \} =f(\sigma(M))=\sigma(f(M))=\sigma\left(\frac{M}{I+M}\right)$$
but since $\frac{\lambda_i}{1+\lambda_i}\geq 0$, $\frac{M}{I+M}$ is also positive semi-definite.

That's very elegant, thank you. I wasn't aware of the spectral mapping theorem...

We have
\begin{align*}
 (I + M)^{-1}M
 &= (I + M)^{-1}M(I + M)(I + M)^{-1}\\
 &= (I + M)^{-1}M(I + M)^{-1} + (I + M)^{-1}M^2(I + M)^{-1}.
\end{align*}
We have (Note: $(I + M)^{-1}M$ is also symmetric.)
\begin{align*}
 x^\top (I + M)^{-1}M x
 &= x^{\top} (I + M)^{-1}M(I + M)^{-1} x
 + x^\top (I + M)^{-1}M^2(I + M)^{-1} x\\
 &= y^\top M y + z^\top z\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where $y = (I + M)^{-1} x$ and $z = M(I + M)^{-1} x$.
We are done.
